# Filter a list based on two parameters

Tags: scala

I want to filter a list based on a parameter in scala

```
   case class Student(
   name:String,
   age:Int,
   subjects:List[Subject]
  )
  
  case class Subject(name:String,id:Int)

  val sub1=Subject("maths",101)
  val sub2=Subject("science",102)
  val sub3=Subject("english",103)
  val s1=Student("abc",20,List(sub1,sub2))
  val s2=Student("def",30,List(sub3,sub1))
  val s3=Student("XYZ",40,List(sub3,sub2))

  val sList=List(s1,s2)

 def findSubjectId(sList: List[Student], subject:String) {

 sList.map(student => student.copy(subjects =
    student.subjects.filter(_.name == subject)))
}
```

1. Parameter 1 - Subject
2. Parameter 2 - age with 20 OR 30

   Result- It should be optional

Comment: Please share what you've tried, and the results.

Comment: updated .I am unable to apply filter on 2 fields

Comment: So your questions is answered then?

Comment: I have only filtered on subject .I want to filter on age and subject both

Comment: You can chain a second .filter() on whatever field you want.

Comment: can u please give a example I have tried it but it doesnt work

Comment: @DonBranson `sList.filter(_.age == 20)`,not sure how to chain it

Comment: What is the desired return type of your `findSubjectId`? Function name implies `Option[Int]` but your current implementation would give something completely different.  Also, why the call to the `copy` method?

Comment: Mahesh's answer shows how to chain them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 sList
   .map(student => student.copy(
     subjects = student.subjects
       .filter(_.name == subject)))
   .filter(student => student.age == 20 || student.age == 30)
```